# Converting CLLocationCoordinate2D into PFGeoPoint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, geopoints, cllocationcoordinate2d

I get user's current location with CLLocationCoordinate2D then would like to use it for Parse's nearGeoPoint.

I know I can just simply use geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground but I'd rather retrieve with CLLocationCoordinate2D instead.

Comment: `geoPointWithLatitude:longitude:`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `geoPointWithLatitude:longitude:` initializer of the PFGeoPoint class. Give it the latitude and longitude values of your CLLocationCoordinate2D, and you'll have your PFGeoPoint.

e.g.

```
PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
```

Comment: Could you expand upon your answer? Why would this code snippet work, for instance?

Comment: Hi @evolutionxbox. I don't understand your question clearly.  Anyway, you can find more details here: https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFGeoPoint.html

Comment: I was wondering if you could add your own explanation to the answer, as it's quite short.

Comment: @evolutionxbox. I'm sorry. Because the question is simple and clear, I think my answer is enough to understand.

Comment: I wasn't accusing you of any wrongdoing, I had hoped a little more explanation would be helpful. I can understand wanting to keep it simple though.

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox. I am new here.